# cast string to JSON

Tags: php, json, yii, casting

Is there any way to make `PHP` look at a `string` as a `JSON`?
I have a `string`, in a `JSON` format of course, and I want to perform actions on it like it was an array. However I don't want to use `CJSON::decode` because it takes a long time, Is there a way?
Example for the string:

```
{"myArray":[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3","key4":"val4"},
{"key1":"val2_1","key2":"val2_2","key3":"val2_3","key4":"val2_4"}]}
```

Comment: can you put your JSON string

Comment: @NiravRanpara look now

Answer (score 0):

how about `json_decode()` ?

I don't think there is faster than that

```
$string = '{"myArray":[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3","key4":"val4"},    {"key1":"val2_1","key2":"val2_2","key3":"val2_3","key4":"val2_4"}]}';
$array = json_decode($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what CJSON::decode is but you have to decode the string so you can use the built in function `json_decode($str);`